# API Management layer in .NET

Tags: asp.net, wcf, api, authentication, rate-limiting

I am currently exposing an API endpoint for my .net services which uses WCF Rest API, ASP.NET Web API and ServiceStack.

I want to add rate limiting and authentication for my API, to add this I don't want to implement authentication/rate limit in each service.

Do you know if there is some platform (open source is a must) that I can put after my services that will manage it? like apigee?